# How to map JSON data from newsAPI in React App?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Here is the JSON:

```
{"status":"ok","totalResults":38,"articles":[{"source":{"id":null,"name":"Vulture"},"author":"Halle Kiefer","title":"Chris D’Elia Says ‘Sex Controlled My Life’ in First YouTube Video After Sexual Misconduct Claims - Vulture","description":"The comedian repeated his previous assertion that all of his relationships have been “consensual and legal.”","url":"http://www.vulture.com/2021/02/chris-delia-denies-sexual-misconduct-claims-in-new-video.html","urlToImage":"https://pyxis.nymag.com/v1/imgs/52f/895/010feba0fce74701cd59d05fee82cd8f3e-19-Chris-DElia.1x.rsocial.w1200.jpg","publishedAt":"2021-02-20T04:44:14Z","content":"Months after multiple accusations of sexual harassment and misconduct led to Netflix pulling his upcoming prank show, former costar Whitney Cummings condemning his pattern of predatory behavior, and … [+1667 chars]"},{"source":{"id":null,"name":"Bleeding Green Nation"},"author":"Brandon Lee Gowton","title":"Carson Wentz finally breaks silence to say goodbye to Philadelphia - Bleeding Green Nation","description":"Hear from the former Eagles quarterback.","url":"https://www.bleedinggreennation.com/2021/2/19/22292387/carson-wentz-finally-breaks-silence-goodbye-philadelphia-message-instagram-trade-colts-quarterback","urlToImage":"https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/_39FOw4LUCxXPeLQzJWmPO4UAhM=/0x0:3650x1911/fit-in/1200x630/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/22316651/usa_today_13471769.jpg","publishedAt":"2021-02-20T04:31:15Z","content":"Carson Wentz finally broke his silence.\r\nWe previously hadnt heard directly from the now-former Eagles quarterback (aside from a Twitter ad) since his postgame press conference after getting benched … [+1420 chars]"},{"source":{"id":"the-times-of-india","name":"The Times of India"},"author":"Reuters","title":"'Something we've never seen' - Mars rover beams back selfie from moment before landing - Times of India","description":"US News: The color photograph, likely to become an instant classic among memorable images from the history of spaceflight, was snapped by a camera mounted on t","url":"https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/world/us/something-weve-never-seen-mars-rover-beams-back-selfie-from-moment-before-landing/articleshow/81121548.cms","urlToImage":"https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-81121566,width-1070,height-580,imgsize-119979,resizemode-75,overlay-toi_sw,pt-32,y_pad-40/photo.jpg","publishedAt":"2021-02-20T04:16:00Z","content":"'Something we've never seen' - Mars rover beams back selfie from moment before landing\r\n<ul><li>News</li>\r\n<li>World News</li>\r\n<li>US News</li>\r\n<li>'Something we've never seen' - Mars rover beams b… [+46 chars]"},{"source":{"id":null,"name":"PEOPLE"},"author":"Naledi Ushe","title":"Anne Hathaway Says She Was the Ninth Choice for Devil Wears Prada Role: 'Never Give Up' - msnNOW","description":"Rachel McAdams was the production company’s first choice for the part of Andy Sachs","url":"https://people.com/movies/anne-hathaway-ninth-choice-devil-wears-prada-role/","urlToImage":"https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?q=85&c=sc&poi=%5B679%2C220%5D&w=1333&h=667&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F20%2F2021%2F02%2F18%2Fgolden-globes-anne-hathaway-2000.jpg","publishedAt":"2021-02-20T04:10:29Z","content":"Anne Hathaway is one tough cookie when it comes to the acting industry.\r\nHathaway, 38, who had to fight to land her part in the 2006 comedy-drama, The Devil Wears Prada, revealed during an appearance… [+1923 chars]"},{"source":{"id":"fox-news","name":"Fox News"},"author":"Nate Day","title":"Meghan Markle, Prince Harry will no longer serve as patrons for some organizations - Fox News","description":"Prince Harry and Meghan Markle will no longer serve as patrons for a number of organizations including the Queen's Commonwealth Trust and the Rugby Football Union.","url":"https://www.foxnews.com/entertainment/meghan-markle-prince-harry-no-longer-patrons-organizations","urlToImage":"https://static.foxnews.com/foxnews.com/content/uploads/2021/01/cac1d84a-Meghan-Markle-prince-harry-timeline-photo.jpg","publishedAt":"2021-02-20T03:08:11Z","content":"Meghan Markle and Prince Harry will no longer serve as patrons for several organizations following the confirmation of their royal exit.\r\nIn early 2020, the pair announced that they'd walk away from … [+2656 chars]"},{"source":{"id":"the-hill","name":"The Hill"},"author":"Tal Axelrod","title":"More airlines to start collecting contact tracing information from passengers | TheHill - The Hill","description":"More airlines said Friday they will start asking for passengers’ personal information on flights to the U.S. to beef up their contact tracing capabilities.","url":"https://thehill.com/policy/transportation/539696-more-airlines-to-start-collecting-contact-tracing-information-from","urlToImage":"https://thehill.com/sites/default/files/airplane10082020.jpg","publishedAt":"2021-02-20T02:50:39Z","content":"More airlines said Friday they will start asking for passengers personal information on flights to the U.S. to beef up their contact tracing capabilities.\r\nAirlines for America, an industry trade gro… [+1639 chars]"},{"source":{"id":null,"name":"Daily Beast"},"author":"Cheyenne Roundtree","title":"The Curious Timing of Kim Kardashian's Divorce From Kanye West - The Daily Beast","description":"The family has long utilized their popular reality show to address situations they wouldn’t elaborate on in real time, instead waiting for the dust to settle to have the final say.","url":"https://www.thedailybeast.com/the-curious-timing-of-kim-kardashians-divorce-from-kanye-.....}]}
```

Here is the code:

```
export const App = () => {
    const [newsId, setNewsId] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        NewsAPI()
         .then(data => JSON.stringify(data))
         .then(data => setNewsId(data));
         return () => {};
     }, []);
     return (<> {newsId.map(data => <NewsCard key={newsId} newsID={data}/>)} </>
};
```

I tried to map JSON array from newsAPI.

When I simply print out the parameter, I received full JSON data.

But I get the error:

> TypeError: newsId.map is not a function

when I tried to map data and order the result by its title.I got full JSON data if I just set {newsId} instead of mapping it.

I have tried `{newsId.articles}` and `{newsId['articles]}`, but both return nothing.

Comment: you should be probably running this `(<> {newsId.map(data => <NewsCard key={newsId} newsID={data}/>)}` into the component, as you are already using a state, `then(data => setNewsId(data));` will update the state, and hence the component.

the time you are trying to return the whole component, newsId is not set yet, due to Javascript's asynchronous nature.

Comment: You shouldn't be stringifying the data. You should do `data.json()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the description for JSON function here:

- JSON.parse() takes a JSON string and transforms it into a JavaScript
  object.
- JSON.stringify() takes a JavaScript object and transforms it into a
  JSON string.

In this case the fetch api always return Response Object. This is just an HTTP response, not the actual JSON. To extract the JSON body content from the response, we use the json() method.
And after that you can use newsId.articles to get articles list

```
const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    NewsAPI()
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data => setArticles(data.articles));
     return () => {};
 }, []);

 return <>{articles.map(data => <NewsCard key={newsId} newsID={data}/>)}</>
```